# Apply style to all TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

Hi The problem am having is that I have multiple TreeView control and each TreeView has its own TreeViewItem styles,
setting it

> TreeView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Style1}"

will only set the root element NOT all the child elements, How to apply a style to all the child elements in a TreeView

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this:

You could make your style the default for all TreeViewItems:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
...
</Style>
```

The difference is that you do not set the x:Key attribute, but you do set the TargetType attribute. You do not need to set the ItemContainerStyle on your TreeView in this case.

---

You could also set your style as the default style for all TreeViewItems, but only within your TreeView:

```xml
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Style1}"/>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

In this case you also do not need to set the ItemContainerStyle on your TreeView.

---

You could also alter your style as follows

```xml
<Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource Style1}"/>
</Style>
```

In this case you'd still have to set the ItemContainerStyle on your TreeView.

Comment: I think it worth to mention about DataTemplates. Who knows, maybe Chandimal wants to change content of TreeViewItem, not the container style, but doesn't realize this... Just a thought :).

Comment: Thanks!, This is what I was looking for!. Its about changing the background /selection color etc.