# Applying WPF styles to Child Items

Tags: wpf, grid, styles

Lets say I have a grid, within my grid I have a number of controls.  Instead of setting the margin for each of these controls, I wish to create a style to set the margin for ANY control I drop into a grid. Is this possible?

I was hoping that the following would work:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DefaultMargins">
        <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="3, 3, 3, 3"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Style="{StaticResource DefaultMargins}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="button1">Button</Button>
</Grid>
```

But the Margin is ignored, it not supporting property value inheritance.  Is there a simple alternative to apply the margins to each 'child' of the grid?  I understand that it is possible to achieve this sort of thing in CSS and some of our developers are interested in using this sort of construct.

Thanks
Ian

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I ask because I have the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can specify the style by type and constrain it to the scope of the `Grid`:

```
    <Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="3, 3, 3, 3"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="button1">Button</Button>
```

Comment: This will however also apply to children of children and so on. See my answer below for exact solution using `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: I tried your code, but was unable to get it to work. After digging deeper, I found that WPF does not apply a style to a control when that style's TargetType property is set to that control's base class.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026635/setting-a-styles-targettype-property-to-a-base-class

Comment: This used to work. I don't post code that I do not dog food.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to answer a similar question to yours:
[Apply style to all TreeViewItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366598/apply-style-to-all-treeviewitem)

If that doesn't work then I'm not too sure about how it would be done in XAML but you could add the style in the code-behind with:

```
Control element;

for (int i = 0; i < Grid1.Children.Count; i++)
{
    element = (Control) Grid1.Children[i];
    element.Style = (Style) FindResource("DefaultMargins");
}
```

Edit: Grid1 refers to a x:Name="Grid1" property added to the XAML grid (poor naming I know).

Answer (score 0):

Place elements inside `ItemsControl` with `ItemsPanel` set to `Grid` and `ItemContainerStyle` to your style:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="DefaultMargins">
    <Setter Property="Control.Margin"
            Value="3, 3, 3, 3" />
    <Setter Property="Control.FontSize"
            Value="50" />
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<ItemsControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DefaultMargins}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
          <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      </Grid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

  <Button Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Name="button1">Button</Button>

</ItemsControl>
```

This has a drawback of not working well with designer.

Comment: this appears to be exactly what I was looking for. If I come back later,  try it out and it works,then I'll upvote.