# Change background color on group of objects with ismouseover

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am really new to WPF+C# and trying to catch up with lots of tutorials at msdn and here at stack. I am currently trying to change the colour of all the objects (at the same time) below (drawing of a house) on **ismouseover** . I can do this with one object (triggers in the code below) at a time but cant figure out some way to change all colours at the same time, here is my xaml code, i have not added anything to xaml.cs I guess that i need to create some for loop but I do not understand how to link the objects drawn in xaml to the code in xaml.cs

```
<Window x:Class="LAB2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600">
<Canvas>

    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="86" Canvas.Top="190" Height="171" Name="body" Stroke="Black" Width="387"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="118" Canvas.Top="229" Height="82"  Name="window" Stroke="Black" Width="89"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="346" Canvas.Top="229" Height="132"  Name="door" Stroke="Black" Width="83"/>
    <Polygon Points="10,110 230,10 500,110" Fill="Blue" Stroke="Black" Name="triangle" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="86" />
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="156" Canvas.Top="109" Height="61" Name="chimney" Stroke="Black" Width="36">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
<Window.Resources>

</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: This related question may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465806/applying-wpf-styles-to-child-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to move triggers higher... and because you can use triggers only within ControlTemplate or Style my solution is little tricky.

```
    <Control>
        <Control.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Canvas>
                    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="86" Canvas.Top="190" Height="171" Fill="Blue" Name="body" Stroke="Black" Width="387"/>
                    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="118" Canvas.Top="229" Height="82" Fill="Blue"  Name="window" Stroke="Black" Width="89"/>
                    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="346" Canvas.Top="229" Fill="Blue" Height="132"  Name="door" Stroke="Black" Width="83"/>
                    <Polygon Points="10,110 230,10 500,110" Fill="Blue" Stroke="Black" Name="triangle" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="86" />
                    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="156" Canvas.Top="109" Height="61" Fill="Blue" Name="chimney" Stroke="Black" Width="36">
                    </Rectangle>
                </Canvas>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="body" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter TargetName="window" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter TargetName="door" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter TargetName="triangle" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="body" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                        <Setter TargetName="window" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                        <Setter TargetName="door" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                        <Setter TargetName="triangle" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>-->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>     
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Control.Template>
    </Control>
```

When you don't set Background property in Canvas you get better behavior because canvas will ignore IsMouseOver and Trigger will work only when you move your cursor over one of objects within Canvas

Answer (score 1):

You could remove your style triggers, and attach methods to the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events in the .xaml.cs file:

```
    private void body_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var c in canvas.Children)
        {
            if(c is Shape) (c as Shape).Fill = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }

    private void body_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var c in canvas.Children)
        {
            if (c is Shape) (c as Shape).Fill = Brushes.Blue;
        }
    }
```

This seems like the brute force method, but it works.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this solution, it really is a bit forceful but i think it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also, You can define a base style for Shape and then derive it for Polygon and rectangle.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ShapeMouseOverStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Shape}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ShapeMouseOverStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Polygon}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ShapeMouseOverStyle}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="86" Canvas.Top="190" Height="171" Name="body" Stroke="Black" Width="387"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="118" Canvas.Top="229" Height="82"  Name="window" Stroke="Black" Width="89"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="346" Canvas.Top="229" Height="132"  Name="door" Stroke="Black" Width="83"/>
        <Polygon Points="10,110 230,10 500,110" Fill="Blue" Stroke="Black" Name="triangle" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="86" />
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="156" Canvas.Top="109" Height="61" Name="chimney" Stroke="Black" Width="36"/>
    </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

Cheers...