# Change TreeViewItem background based on an attached property

Tags: wpf, background, treeview, styles, treeviewitem

I am trying to change the background of the TreeViewItems in a TreeView, based on an a property (boolean) attached to the TreeViewItems. I've tried this :

```
    <local:BooleanToBrushConverter x:Key="BooleanToBrushConverter" 
                                   TrueBrush="Yellow" FalseBrush="Transparent"/>


    <local:TreeViewEx ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=(local:TreeViewItemExtensions.Selected), 
                                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                              Converter={StaticResource BooleanToBrushConverter}}"/>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
        </TreeView.Resources>

        ...

    </local:TreeViewEx>
```

Ran the app, but although I've (programatically) set the property (Selected, not to be confused with IsSelected) to true on the "Child" TreeViewItem the background was not set

I've taken a look with Snoop and found that it doesn't have the yellow background as it should (the converter fires and returns correctly) :

[image]

However, taking a peek in Snoop it shows that the Yellow brush **has been applied** to that TreeViewItem :

[image]

However if I manually set the background to the parent Stackpanel ([016] in Snoop) it reflects that value. But I can't get to it by the style..

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE** : It seems that the currently selected item has some kind of style that needs addressing somehow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem results from the fact that TreeView.ItemContainerStyle [only applies to the root item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366598/apply-style-to-all-treeviewitem). If you replace TreeView.ItemContainerStyle by a default style for TreeViewItem in TreeView.Resources you get a style that applies to all items (in that TreeView):

```
    <TreeView>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <!-- default style instead of ItemContainerStyle -->
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{Binding Path=(local:TreeViewItemExtensions.Selected), 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToBrushConverter}}"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Root" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Child"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Child" Name="testChild"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Child"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

Now setting the Selected attached property works:

```
TreeViewItemExtensions.SetSelected(testChild, true);
```